# Karate Extract () is not recognised as a function ,Karate version used is 0.9.5

Tags: karate

Karate.extract() is not being recognised
And header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ tkn1
Then status 200
def htmlresponse = response
def extracted = karate.extract(htmlresponse,'code+value=\"([^\"]+)',1)

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="SomeURL">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="1234" ng-non-bindable />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="123" ng-non-bindable />
```

karate.extract(HTMLResponse,'HtmlResponse+value=\"([^\"]+)',1), TypeError: karate.extract is not a function in  at line number 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think this is a new API. Please upgrade to the latest version 1.2.0